# Meteor: push notifications when App closed with raix:push in Android

Tags: android, meteor, push-notification

I'm new in Meteor.

Now I'm trying with Cordova integration, mainly with push notifications using the raix:push plugin for Meteor.

The App receives simple notifications when it's running in background although I haven't managed to receive the images within the notification.

The main problem takes place when the app is completely closed, as it can't receive notifications, and the server doesn`t drop any error message.

The App is deployed in Heroku server.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% mobile-config.js  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

App.configurePlugin('phonegap-plugin-push', {
  SENDER_ID: XXXXXXXXXXX
});


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% client/main.js %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';

Push.Configure({
 android: {
  senderID: XXXXXXXXXXX,
  alert: true,
  badge: true,
  sound: true,
  vibrate: true,
  clearNotifications: true
  // icon: '',
  // iconColor: ''
 },
});

Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
 // counter starts at 0
 this.counter = new ReactiveVar(0);
});

Template.hello.helpers({
  counter() {
   return Template.instance().counter.get();
  },
});

Template.hello.events({
 'click button'(event, instance) {
   // increment the counter when button is clicked
   instance.counter.set(instance.counter.get() + 1);
 },

});

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% server/main.js %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
 // code to run on server at startup

 Push.Configure({
  gcm: {
    apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  },
  production: true,
 });

});

Meteor.methods({
 sendPush: function() {
  return Push.send({
   from: 'Test',
      title:'Greetings',
      text:'Hello world!',
      badge: 3,
      query: {},
    });
   },
});
```

The mesagge is sent in the server shell

```
> Meteor.call('sendPush');
```

I'm using the next versions:

```
// Meteor@1.4.3.1
// raix:push@3.0.2
// cordova-plugin-device@1.1.4
// phonegap-plugin-push@1.9.4
```

I don't understand what the problem is and I spent a lot of time trying to find a solution. Any help will be welcome.

Comment: facing a similar issue. were you able to resolve it?

Comment: There might several reasons for push notifications problems. Can you pls provide related client (mobile app) and server logs, first?